# Perl PDF line by line Parser?

Tags: perl, pdf, pdf-parsing

I have a pdf, consists only of text, with no special characters nor images etc.
Is there any Perl module out there (Been looking at cpan to no avail) to help me parse each page line by line?
(Converting the PDF to text yields bad results and unparsable data)

Thanks,

Comment: A PDF is not a text file. It's not even plain text markup.

Comment: What program did you use to try converting PDF to text, pdftotext? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I want to extract text from a PDF, I feed it to `pdftohtml` (part of [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)) using the `-xml` output option.  This produces an XML file which I parse using [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig) (or any other XML parser you like except XML::Simple).

[The XML format](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/tree/utils/pdf2xml.dtd) is fairly simple.  You get a `<page>` element for each page in the PDF, which contains `<fontspec>` elements describing the fonts used and a `<text>` element for each line of text.  The `<text>` elements may contain `<b>` and `<i>` tags for bold and italic text (which is why XML::Simple can't parse it properly).

You do need to use the `top` and `left` attributes of the `<text>` tags to get them in the right order, because they aren't necessarily emitted in top-to-bottom order.  The coordinate system has 0,0 in the upper left corner of the page with down and right being positive.  Dimensions are in PostScript points (72 points per inch).