# How to parse .pdf files in Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf

How to parse .pdf files in Perl?
Is perl is more efficient or should I use any other language?

Comment: There is no such thing as [PERL](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f)

Comment: Good point, @David -- on the other hand, Perl is very good at parsing **text** files. It may not be the *best* tool for parsing PDF.

Comment: Perl is perfectly fine for parsing PDF.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/139015 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1136990 http://stackoverflow.com/q/4049486 http://stackoverflow.com/q/4730651 http://stackoverflow.com/q/5021737 http://stackoverflow.com/q/5664973 http://stackoverflow.com/q/5977086 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-parsing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally use CAM::PDF.

```
my $doc=CAM::PDF->new($fileName) || die "$CAM::PDF::errStr\n"; CAM::PDF>asciify(/$pdfString);`
```

Pdfs are not designed for parsing, but for display/printing - thus anything is always try and error and it is quite possible that it is impossible to parse if everything is graphics.
 A good indicator is if you can copy and paste the content from the pdf into an editor. If this works, then you are in business.

Comment: This code snippet is incomplete - where does $pdfString come from, I assume the / is a typo? As is "CAM::PDF>asciify"

Answer (score 10):

When I want to extract text from a PDF, I feed it to `pdftohtml` (part of [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)) using the `-xml` output option.  This produces an XML file which I parse using [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig) (or any other XML parser you like except XML::Simple).

[The XML format](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/tree/utils/pdf2xml.dtd) is fairly simple.  You get a `<page>` element for each page in the PDF, which contains `<fontspec>` elements describing the fonts used and a `<text>` element for each line of text.  The `<text>` elements may contain `<b>` and `<i>` tags for bold and italic text (which is why XML::Simple can't parse it properly).

You do need to use the `top` and `left` attributes of the `<text>` tags to get them in the right order, because they aren't necessarily emitted in top-to-bottom order.  The coordinate system has 0,0 in the upper left corner of the page with down and right being positive.  Dimensions are in PostScript points (72 points per inch).

Comment: If, say, in the pdf, you have a table of data, does the XML tell you easily where the columns of data start and end, or is it just a big text../text node where you still have to guess at what the column boundaries are as in the pdftotext converted text document?

Comment: It depends on how the PDF was generated.  I'd expect one text node per cell, but I don't think I've ever tried a document like that.

Comment: I've tested it on one document, and for the most part, each cell is a text node. But occasionally, the first column is merged with the next column in the same text node. Luckily, this is easy for me to separate, but I haven't looked closely enough to find other issues yet...but it looks promising...thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [the CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=pdf&mode=all) and, specifically, if you want to do OCR, see [PDF::OCR2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PDF%3a%3aOCR2)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any module that parses, that is, if you to extract the text from them.  There are a number of modules that let you manipulate them.  Try [PDF::API2](http://search.cpan.org/~ssimms/PDF-API2-2.019/lib/PDF/API2.pm).